# Split the string with different conditions using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I need to extract and remove a word from a string. The word should be upper-case, and following one of the delimiters `/`, `;`, `(`, `-` or a space.

Some Examples:

1. `"this is test A/ABC"`
   Expected output: `"this is test A"` and `"ABC"`
2. `"this is a test; ABC/XYZ"`
   Expected output: `"this is a test; ABC"` and  `"XYZ"`
3. `"This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in our project"`
   Expected output: `"This TASK is assigned to ANIL in our project"` and  `"SHAM"`
4. `"This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in OUR project"`
   Expected output: `"This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in project"` and  `"OUR"`
5. `"this is test AWN.A"`
   Expected output: `"this is test"` and  `"AWN.A"`
6. `"XETRA-DAX"`
   Expected output: `"XETRA"` and  `"DAX"`
7. `"FTSE-100"`
   Expected output: `"-100"` and  `"FTSE"`
8. `"ATHEX"`
   Expected output: `""` and  `"ATHEX"`
9. `"Euro-Stoxx-50"`
   Expected output: `"Euro-Stoxx-50"` and  `""`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with LINQ and not, say, a regex?

Comment: Is this homework? Sounds a bit like it.

Comment: Please provide what you have produced yourself so far.

Comment: Hope Linq gives optimum code length for finding matches and searching the match/substring within the string at very fast rate.

Comment: As Ilya Kogan said regular expressions are perfect for your case.

Comment: Please provide response for my update in question.

Comment: Please provide response for this post

Comment: sukumar - It is impossible that all answers are wrong, specifically when some are correct (working and have the same result as in your question). Can you please explain what we all got wrong? `:)`

Comment: sukumar - Honestly, I find it very difficult and even frustrating to try to help you - you keep making up new rules after a few days, or simple say "does not work". Consider cleaning up the question - explain your rules in a few sentences, and give simple input/output examples for each case you can think of.

Comment: sukumar - I've went ahead and edited the question for you, trying to keep only what's relevant (Linq *isn't* relevant, nor is the blurb about intelligence and optimization), I narrowed it down to the heart of the question. If you don't like it you can (and should) rollback, but I suggest you edit it extensively. Good luck.

Comment: `AWN.A` raises a new issue - you are no longer dealing with uppercase words... Can you please explain what sorts of characters are you trying to extract?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Homework or work-work it doesn't really matter.  You are assigned one to learn and you are assigned the other to get paid; either way you are assigned something and are expected to complete it.

Comment: Sure. But if it is homework, the answers should explain a little bit more what is going on, because the main reason for homework is to learn something. If it would be for work, it is not so important that the OP learns something, because the work work just needs to be completed and run.

Comment: @Will: Obviously, you didn't understand my comment.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yaknow, I think you're onto something there.

Comment: @Will: I don't understand your comment, sorry. What I meant: If it is homework, the answers should be more verbose so that the OP learns something. This doesn't mean, that I don't want to answer homework questions, quite the contrary!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: you: "Obviously, you didn't understand my comment" me: "You know, I think you're onto something there" i.e., "I think you're right".

Comment: @Will: haha, ok. No hard feelings, I hope!

Comment: With combination of input strings still i'm not getting the proper output. Even with bounty couldn't get the expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a List of strings, set all the words to it

find the index of the `/` then use `ElementAt()` to determine the word to split which is "SHAM" in your question.

in the below sentence of yours your index of `/` will be 6.

```
string strSentence ="This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in our project";
```

then use `ElementAt(6)` at the end of

`index` is the index of the `/` in your `List<string>`

```
str = str.Select(s => strSentence.ElementAt(index+1)).ToList();
```

this will return you the SHAM

```
str = str.Delete(s => strSentence.ElementAt(index+1));
```

this will delete the SHAM then just print the strSentence without SHAM

if you dont want to use a list of strings you can use the " " to determinate the words in your sentence i think, but that would be a long way to go.

the idea of mine is right i think but the code may not be that flawless.

Comment: Seems still you are not getting this query what exactly i need. 
here i mentioned as an example with a sentence but dynamically i want split just after the delimiter(/) and checking the uppercase condition etc.
Please ready my question from beginning and go through both scenarios and reply.

Comment: i did i still believe what i wrote is a very easy way to do that also Paolo's code must be working i think

Answer (score 14):

An "intelligent" version:

```
    string strValue = "this is test A/ABC";
    int ix = strValue.LastIndexOfAny(new[] { '/', ' ', ';', '(', '-' });
    var str1 = strValue.Substring(0, ix);
    var str2 = strValue.Substring(ix + 1);
```

A "stupid LINQ" version:

```
    var str3 = new string(strValue.Reverse().SkipWhile(p => p != '/' && p != ' ' && p != ';' && p != '(' && p != '-').Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray());
    var str4 = new string(strValue.Reverse().TakeWhile(p => p != '/' && p != ' ' && p != ';' && p != '(' && p != '-').Reverse().ToArray());
```

both cases are WITHOUT checks. The OP can add checks if he wants them.

For the second question, using LINQ is REALLY too much difficult. With a Regex it's "easily doable".

```
var regex = new Regex("^(.*[A-Z]+)([-/ ;(]+)([A-Z]+)(.*?)$");

var strValueWithout = regex.Replace(strValue, "$1$4");
var extractedPart = regex.Replace(strValue, "$3");
```

For the third question

```
var regex = new Regex("^(.*?)([A-Z.]*)([-/ ;(]+)([A-Z.]+)(.*?)$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

var strValueWithout = regex.Replace(strValue, "$1$2$5");
var extractedPart = regex.Replace(strValue, "$4");
```

With code sample: http://ideone.com/5OSs0

Another update (it's becoming BORING)

```
Regex Regex = new Regex(@"^(?<1>.*?)(?<2>[-/ ;(]*)(?<=\b)(?<3>[A-Z.]+)(?=\b)(?<4>.*?)$|^(?<1>.*)$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
Regex Regex2 = new Regex(@"^(?<1>.*?)(?<2>[-/ ;(]*)(?<=\b)(?<3>(?:\p{Lu}|\.)+)(?=\b)(?<4>.*?)$|^(?<1>.*)$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

var str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "$1$4");
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str, "$3");
```

The difference between the two is that the first will use A-Z as upper case characters, the second one will use other "upper case" characters, for example `ÀÈÉÌÒÙ`

With code sample: http://ideone.com/FqcmY

Comment: Lets consider another string as below: 

string strSentence ="This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in our project"; 

I need two sub-strings as follows: 

1) This TASK is assigned to ANIL in our project 
2) SHAM 

Does the above code gives the solution(Split at Uppercase words with delimiter) which i expects as mentioned?

Comment: @sukumar You should learn to pose better questions, in all your post you din't mention you needed to split AND extract "couples" of uppercase words.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Now I modified the question with different scenarios clearly.

Comment: Nice one. A small comment: `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` is useful for finding the last match, but I don't think it helps here - the match is from start to end either way, and the flag doesn't change the pattern, just the way it is tried to be matched.

Comment: @Kobi Yeah... right... It remained from a previous "incarnation" of the regex.

Comment: This code doesn't give the expected result with both scenarios(scenario 1 and 2)

Comment: @sukumar Perhaps you have problems with your computer, because I just retested them with your examples and they work correctly. And if you want to check it online: http://ideone.com/1yY3y

Comment: @Xanatos,

There is one more condition in order to get a part of word or substring from the string. 
Lets take this string with some change.
string strSentence ="This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in OUR project"; 

The output should be in two strings as below. 
**This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in project**
 as one string 
and 
**OUR** as another string.

Comment: Here the last capitalized word is taken into consideration while split from the whole string. This is also a condition to check and require the split appropriately. The above code doesn't give the result as i mentioned which i expected. in case if there is no uppercase words after 'SHAM' then only SHAM part would be separated. Hope you got it now. Provide me the code which gives the output by considering this condition as well.

Comment: +1 for a comrade in battle. I suspect you can greatly simplify it for the new requirements, something like `^(.*)[-/ ;(]([A-Z.]+)(.*)$` should be enough - it seems you can simply ignore the word before the separator.

Comment: @xanatos -  I need the code to handle 6,7,8 patterns as well. Please help.

Comment: @Xanatos - check for pattern 9.

Comment: @xanatos. +1 for going all out on this one. you deserve a badge or something for all the effort you've put in.

Answer (score 6):

This should work according to the new requirements:  it should find the last separator that is wrapped with uppercase words:

```
Match lastSeparator = Regex.Match(strExample,
                                  @"(?<=\b\p{Lu}+)[-/ ;(](\p{Lu}+)\b",
                                  RegexOptions.RightToLeft); // last match
string main = lastSeparator.Result("$`$'");  // before and after the match
string word = lastSeparator.Groups[1].Value; // word after the separator
```

This regex is a little tricky. Main tricks:

- Use `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` to find the last match.
- Use of [Match.Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.result.aspx) for a replace.
- `` $`$' `` as replacement string: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html
- `\p{Lu}` for upper-case letters, you can change that to `[A-Z]` if your more comfortable with that.

---

- If the word shouldn't follow an upper case word, you can simplify the regex to:

  ```
  @"[-/ ;(](\p{Lu}+)\b"
  ```
- If you want other characters as well, you can use a character class (and maybe remove `\b`). For example:

  ```
  @"[-/ ;(]([\p{Lu}.,]+)"
  ```

Working example: **http://ideone.com/U9AdK**

Comment: This code doesn't give the expected result as mentioned with both scenarios(scenario 1 and 2)

Comment: @sukumar - How is that? I renamed a variable so the code would compile. Aside from that, it looks right according to both examples: http://ideone.com/nVs2a . What am I missing? Can you please edit the question and explain?

Comment: For this string, 
string strSentence ="This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in OUR project"; 

The output should be  in two strings as below.

**This TASK is assigned to ANIL/SHAM in project** 
as one string and

**OUR** as another string

Comment: Here the last capitalized word is taken into consideration while split from the whole string. This is also a condition to check and require the split appropriately.
The above code doesn't give the result as i mentioned which i expected.

in case if there is no uppercase words after 'SHAM' then only SHAM part would be separated.

Hope you got it now. Provide me the code which gives the output by considering this condition as well.

Comment: @sukumar - If you want the last uppercase word you can use `@"(?<=\b\p{Lu}+)[-/ ;(](\p{Lu}+)\b"`, or just `@"[-/ ;(](\p{Lu}+)\b"`.

Comment: @Kobi - The regex **@"[-/ ;(](\p{Lu}+)\b"** is fine for most of the strings which i checked. But for this string **this is test AWN.A** i need output in two strings as below:
**this is test** as one string and **AWN.A** as another string. With this regex i'm not getting as expected.

Comment: @sukumar - That's because `.` isn't an upper case character (which is a new requirement again ಠ_ಠ ). You can specify the characters you need in the regex, for example, `@"[-/ ;(]([\p{Lu}.,]+)"`, but then it effect `\b`. What if you have `hello CRUEL... world`, or `hello CRUEL...DARK, world`?

Comment: @Kobi - 

I need the code to handle 6,7,8 patterns mentioned in the question. Please provide me the same.

Comment: @sukumar - 6 is already working, and you can get 7 and 8 by changing  `[\-/ ;(]` to `(?:[\-/ ;(]|^)` (I didn't test it though, I'll catch you again after a few more iterations `:)`).

Comment: @Kobi -  For pattern 9, Again the regex doesn't work it seems.
Hope u are getting the same.

Comment: @sukumar - 9 is a no-match, it will work if you add `\b` at the end of the regex: `(?:[\-/ ;(]|^)([\p{Lu}.,]+)\b` . There are many ways to fine-tune it to get what you want, but you have to think about everything beforehand...

Comment: @Kobi:-

For this string `strText = "Entergy Corp. (ETR)";`
I need output in two strings as....
First string = **Energy Corp.**
second string = **ETR**

But currently the first string i'm getting as **Energy Corp. )**.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the `string.Split()` method and the `Regex` class. A simple `Split` is suitable for simple cases, such as splitting according to the character `/`. Regular expressions are perfect for matching more complicated patterns.

Comment: @sukumar are you only looking for LINQ based approach?? If you're looking split and regex based technique i can help you!

Answer (score 3):

As a proof of concept, you could re-implement Split in LINQ using TakeWhile and SkipWhile

```
    string strValue  = "this is test A/ABC";
    var s1=new string(
        strValue
        .TakeWhile(c => c!= '/')
        .ToArray());
    var s2=new string(
        strValue
        .SkipWhile(c => c!= '/')
        .Skip(1)
        .ToArray());
```

I think the resulting code is so mind-blowingly ugly that I hope you'll decide not to use linq

Comment: I updated the question in better understanding with two scenarios. Please provide solution for the query.